# What is the name of inverse of synergy? (finance)

Tags: terminology

I there:
i want to know what is the name / buzzterm (if any) where i have a process and it produce two incomes (monetary or not), for example if i sell a t-shirt with a slogan that say "save the whales" then i profit directly from the t-shirt sales and i also earn a boost from marketing, some sort of 1 ->2.  it usually happens with tax-deduction and charitable foundations.

ps: In business terms, synergy is equal to 1+1>2 (so it is not the opposite but close enough).

Comment: i.e. So you're looking for a term meaning the **opposite** of synergy?

Comment: business speaking yes since i am not adding new source but instead i am using a only source to produce different profits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call it "multiple streams of income" a la Robert Allen and others.

Or you could call it "Do once, sell many" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably call it an intangible or indirect benefit. Not sure what the trade term is.

Comment: thanks too. Apparently there is not a official name and its strange because it is not a strange activity.